# Linear Congruences and Bezout's Identity

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Revising some old texbook, completely confused by the last part of the solution.

So, say I have

10x ≡ 14 (mod 18) - Trying to find the smallest solution.

Let a = 10, b = 14, m = 18.

From the above, we should be able to find x and y with

10x + 18y = 14

by using Bezout's identity, we can find u and v with

10u + 18v = gcm(a,m) = gcm(10,18) = 2 -> 10u + 18v = 2

This gives us b/gcm(a,m) = 14/2 = 7.

A simple solution to the equation derived from the Bezout identity would be : u = 2, v = -1

So if we multiply 10u + 18v = 2 by 7, we get :

107u + 187v = 14

if we let x = 7u and y = 7v and we use the first solution we found : u = 2, v = -1, we get

x = 14, y = -7

I get everything up until here.

Now... This is the part I don not get...

The smallest solution, however is given as :

x = 14 - 18 = -4

y = -7 + 10 = 3

I have no idea where this has been pulled from. I have no idea by what properties I can actually do this.

From my point of view, the author of the book did the following :

x = 14 - 18 = -4 : x = 7u - m

y = -7 + 10 = 3 : y = 7v + a

Could someone explain this one to me please?

Regards.

Comment: Smallest in what sense? The equation has infinitely many integer solutions for $x$ going up and down. There's no smallest among them. Did the author mean the smallest positive (looks like not that) or the smallest by absolute value or in some other sense?

Comment: The question has got me so confused, I'm not even sure they properly understand it. Unless it was through some personal logic of the authore. I'm goint to mail my old prof.